# Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a media server, now I want to add Ubuntu TV

Tags: 14.04, server, ubuntu-tv, kodi

I'm running 14.04 LTS as a media server and I've just come across Ubuntu TV. How do I get access to it? Can I download it and install it on my server copy of Ubuntu or will I have to download a desktop version?

Can someone point me to the instructions on how to download/install it.

Also another question can the Backend (guessing VDR) be accessed via Kodi

Thanks a lot

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "install" Ubuntu TV on Ubuntu 14.04, it is more for TV manufacturer as far as I know. There was a solution for Ubuntu 12.04 as it is still proposed in [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing)

Server or Desktop version doesn't really matter I think.

But if you want to transform your Ubuntu Server into a Media Center, Koki is a good choice. You can install Kodi on your Ubuntu Server without *Desktop Environment*. The procedure is well described ([exemple](https://trick77.com/how-to-install-kodi-ubuntu-server-14-04/)).

You can also share media stored on your server and access them with Kodi installed on another computer. There are some simple techniques to do that such as Samba or NFS sharing, UPnP/DLNA server, etc.